# Expected ";" on javascript .js file?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure what's going on. When I only get the error when I'm declaring a variable. If I use something like console.log("Hey") it runs perfectly.

```
'use strict';


$(document).ready(function() 
{
   Let number;

   console.log("Hey");

});
```

Answer (score 7):

I think it's because you are capitalizing `let`.

Try it lower case since JavaScript is case sensitive i.e.

```
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {
   let number;

   console.log("Hey");
});
```

Comment: Not a problem - I'm glad it helped :)